# Error in AWS Lambda when using pyzstd module

Tags: aws-lambda, python-cffi, zstd

I'm trying to use module pyzstd on Lambda service, but I get the following error:

```
pyzstd module: Neither C implementation nor CFFI implementation can be imported. If pyzstd module is dynamically linked to zstd library, make sure not to remove zstd library, and the run-time zstd library's version can't be lower than that at compile-time.
```

I've installed this library locally on Macbook M1 using command `pip install pyzstd`. Then I zipped site-packages from venv and uploaded it along side with handler code.

Comment: If I read this correctly, according to the [build docs](https://pyzstd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#build-pyzstd), pyzstd module requires zstd v1.4.0+. Check what's available on Amazon Linux 2 kernel 4.14, which is the current OS for Lambda.

Comment: Pyzstd already includes zstd v1.5.4 source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.so` binary file was compiled for M1 & macOS.
If you run it on other architecture/OS, it will fail to import.